# How to open and rename several multi-term buffers on start-up?

Tags: buffers, init-file, term

After each reboot, I have to painfully re-create and rename the
`multi-term` buffers I use in my daily routine.

I am completely new to Lisp, but nonetheless, I searched for similar problem on the web and tried to adapt the code snippets I've found. I managed to open a `multi-term` buffer, but renaming does not work as expected. Here is what I've tried so far in my `init.el`:

```
(require 'multi-term)
(setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")
;; Try to recreate my terminals
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'multi-term)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'get-buffer)
(rename-buffer "redshift")  ;; it renames the previous buffer (not the good one)
```

As a bonus, I would also like to be able to `cd` to a specific directory. Thanks for your advice.

PS: I work on GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (Debian stable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such initialization might (I guess) looks like the following:

```
(require 'multi-term)

(defun init-multi-term (new-name dir)
  (let ((mt-buffer-name "*terminal*"))
    (multi-term)
    (comint-send-string (get-buffer-process mt-buffer-name) (format "cd %s\n" dir))
    (with-current-buffer mt-buffer-name
      (rename-buffer new-name))))

(defun init-multi-terms ()
  (interactive)
  (init-multi-term "Downloads" "/home/demi/Downloads/")
  (init-multi-term "Github" "/str/development/"))

(setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'init-multi-terms)
```

I just tested it and it works fine for me. `cd` works as well.

Comment: On my computer, I had to change `mt-buffer-name "*terminal*"` to `mt-buffer-name "*terminal<1>*"`. And now it works flawlessly.

Comment: This is probably because buffer with the name "*terminal*" already existed.

Answer (score 3):

Technical explanation: that's because `emacs-startup-hook` is run *after* the init file is processed, therefore your call to `multi-term` is run after you do the rename operation.

Now, you don't need `emacs-startup-hook` at all, what you really want is to run those things in sequence, right from your init file. And you don't need to call `get-buffer` (which needs a buffer argument anyway, so that'd never work), since multi-term will display the buffer it creates.

So, try something like:

```
(require 'multi-term)
(setq multi-term-program "/bin/bash")
(multi-term)
(rename-buffer "redshift")
(multi-term)
(rename-buffer "foo")
...
```

or better yet

```
(mapc (lambda (name)
        (multi-term)
        (rename-buffer name))
      '("redshift" "foo"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [Workgroups2](https://github.com/pashinin/workgroups2), which is available via [MELPA](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html).  Although I haven't tried it with Multi-Term (thanks for the pointer, I'd never heard of it!), I'm quite happy with it for saving buffer state between Emacs sessions.

If workgroups2 doesn't work for you, there are pointers to other packages that manage workspaces [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263960/what-is-the-best-emacs-workspaces-plugin).